# Swift Optional Type not Unwrapped

Tags: ios, swift

I've been having a problem probably due to the new updated version of Swift. The problem is that this line of code keeps producing an error saying that:

> "value of optional type '()?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?

```
cell?.hypeImageView?.image = UIImage(data: imageData)
```

This is the entire function:

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, object: PFObject?) -> PFTableViewCell? {

    var cell:HypeTableViewCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier) as? HypeTableViewCell
    if(cell == nil) {
        cell = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("HypeTableViewCell", owner: self, options: nil)[0] as? HypeTableViewCell
    }

    if let pfObject = object {
        cell?.hypeNameLabel?.text = pfObject["name"] as? String

        var votes:Int? = pfObject["votes"] as? Int
        if votes == nil {
            votes = 0
        }
        cell?.hypeVotesLabel?.text = "\(votes!) votes"

        let credit:String? = pfObject["cc_by"] as? String //if prob change to var
        if credit != nil {
            cell?.hypeCreditLabel?.text = "\(credit!) / CC 2.0"
        }

        cell?.hypeImageView?.image = nil
        if var urlString:String? = pfObject["url"] as? String {
            var url:NSURL? = NSURL(string: urlString!)
            if var url:NSURL? = NSURL(string: urlString!) {
                var error:NSError?
                var request:NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url!, cachePolicy: NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReturnCacheDataElseLoad, timeoutInterval: 5.0)

                NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().cancelAllOperations()

                NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(), completionHandler: {
                    (response:NSURLResponse!, imageData:NSData!, error:NSError!) -> Void in

                    cell?.hypeImageView?.image = UIImage(data: imageData)

                })
            }
        }

    }

    return cell

}
```

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using Swift 2.0 change the signature for the `completionHandler` to expect optionals rather than implicitly unwrapped optionals, then the problem will go away.

```
NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) { (response:NSURLResponse?, data:NSData?, error:NSError?) -> Void in

    guard let imageData = data else {
        assertionFailure("No data found")
        return
    }

    cell?.hypeImageView?.image = UIImage(data: imageData)
}
```